# Image not displaying in table response in actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

```
conv.ask(new Table({
                        title: 'Emissions due to different gases',
                        // subtitle: 'Table Subtitle',
                        image: new Image({
                            uri: 'https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Walking-in-Rain.jpg',
                            alt: 'Emissions Image'
                        }),
                        columns: [
                            {
                                header: 'CO2',
                                align: 'CENTER',
                            },
                            {
                                header: 'CH4',
                                align: 'CENTER',
                            },
                            {
                                header: 'N20',
                                align: 'CENTER',
                            },
                        ],
                        rows: [
                            // {
                            //     cells: [carbonEmission, methaneEmission, nitrousEmission],
                            //     dividerAfter: true,
                            // },
                            {
                                cells: ['row 2 item 1', 'row 2 item 2', 'row 2 item 3'],
                                dividerAfter: true,
                            },
                            {
                                cells: ['row 2 item 1', 'row 2 item 2', 'row 2 item 3'],
                            },
                        ],
                        buttons: new Button({
                            title: 'Read More',
                            url: 'https://assistant.google.com'
                        }),
```

I have added this code, I am able to see the table with the given fields but the image is not coming up in the table instead I am getting this error even when the image is https URL.

`MalformedResponse
expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].table_card.image: the protocol must be http or https.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the property inside the `Image` class should probably be called [`url` and not `uri`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/conversation_response.imageoptions.html#url).

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I have copied the table code from the docs as I was learning about it and there it was uri but your suggestion helped me out.

Comment: If there's an issue in the docs, I invite you to file an issue in our [GitHub repo](http://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs).